# How to tie cotter pins around castle/locker nuts?

Tags: wheels

Is there a simple procedure for tying cotter pins around caste or locker nuts?

[image]

Comment: Normally see them sideways. Slide pin through, open. One side wraps left around the axle, other wraps right around the axle. Not seen it over the top before.

Comment: BTW, if the cotter pin arrangement in the image is your work, that's some of the finest I've ever seen. Very clean.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 LOL, it's not -- I pulled it off the interwebs. it is probably factory

Comment: No way that's factory ... looks too nice. That took some care and time which they don't have at the factory.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 -- maybe you think that cuz you work on American vehicles like in that video you sent me... LOL

Answer (score 2):

Just bend it around and make it stay. This is not rocket science. It just needs to hold the cotter (split) pin in place. This will hold the castle nut in place. If there is a cap which goes over the top, then ensure it doesn't interfere with it. Other than that, just *Get 'er Done!*